# Ethernet Information

Tags: c++, windows, networking

Well, i've looked on MSDN about this an only found this: [GetAdaptersAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365915.aspx)

And what i'm trying to get is the Etherned Information, such as Description, Bytes Sent, Bytes Received, Bandwidth, Latency, etc. It's possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get most of that with [`GetIfTable2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365945%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [`GetIfEntry2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365941%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). If you need compatibility with XP and earlier, you'll want to look at [`GetIfTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365943%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [`GetIfEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365939%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) instead. The `*2` functions give more information, but only work on Vista and newer.

I don't believe either will show latency though -- for that you pretty much need to do some measuring. Likewise, the bandwidth will be simply the rated bandwidth of the adapter (e.g., 100 Mb/s or 1000 Mb/s), not what you can necessarily expect when communicating with any particular host.

Edit: Here's some code I had lying around that should show the general idea of how to use these functions:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 

    MIB_IFTABLE *interfaces;
    unsigned long size = 0;
    int i, j;

    GetIfTable(interfaces, &size, FALSE);

    interfaces = (MIB_IFTABLE *)malloc(size);

    GetIfTable(interfaces, &size, TRUE);

    for (i=0; i<interfaces->dwNumEntries; i++) {
        MIB_IFROW &xf = interfaces->table[i];

        printf("%s\n\t", xf.bDescr);
        for (j=0; j<xf.dwPhysAddrLen; j++) {
            printf("%2.2X", xf.bPhysAddr[j]);
            if ( j!= xf.dwPhysAddrLen-1)
                printf(":");
        }
        printf("\n");
        switch(xf.dwType) {
        case MIB_IF_TYPE_ETHERNET:
            printf("Ethernet");
            break;
        case MIB_IF_TYPE_FDDI:
            printf("FDDI");
            break;
        case MIB_IF_TYPE_TOKENRING:
            printf("Token Ring");
            break;
        case MIB_IF_TYPE_LOOPBACK:
            printf("Loopback adapter");
            break;
        case MIB_IF_TYPE_OTHER:
            printf("Other");
            break;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay, i got a part of this. But i don't understand how they work. :/ Sometimes they explain wrong or it's me that i don't get it. :(